# How do to display an icon in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I'm trying to display an icon if the value of key_product is equal to 1.

Here is my controller with what I've tried.

```
return DataTables::of($products)

->editColumn('key_product', function ($row) {
           if('key_product' == 1){
                '<class="btn btn-info btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>';
           }
            return ucfirst($row->key_product);
        })
```

I'm not getting any errors but I still get the database value instead of the icon.

Comment: Not very familiar with Laravel, but it looks like you're not doing anything with ` <class="btn btn-info btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>` . Do you not need to return/assign it?

Comment: Try to understand `if('key_product' == 1){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a return statement for the html content and the html content will be escaped so you have to add the column to the `rawColumns`

From the [docs](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/raw-columns):

> By default, Laravel DataTables protects us from XSS attack by escaping
>   all our outputs. In cases where you want to render an html content,
>   please use rawColumns api.

Something like this:

```
return DataTables::of($products)
    ->editColumn('key_product', function ($row) {
        if ($row->key_product == 1) {
            return '<button class="btn btn-info btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>';
        }
        return ucfirst($row->key_product);
    })
    ->rawColumns(['key_product']);
```

[image: This is what I'm seeing]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Now is just returning the html in the if statement not the icon.

Comment: I updated my answer, the html was incomplete. I added a button around the icon since `<class="btn btn-info btn-circle">` is invalid html.

Comment: Thank you but is still not working. It shows the HTML code in the table instead of the icon.

Comment: I've added the image of what I'm seeing

Comment: did you add `key_product` to the raw columns?

Comment: I mean did you add `->rawColumns(['key_product'])`

Comment: I figure it out I had to add the rawColums at the end of the script. It worked!!! thanks so much